# UITableViewCell on delete doesn't move UITableViewCell's contentView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm running iOS 7 on Xcode 5.1  I have a simple table view cell subclass with a couple labels and a switch.

[image]

All the UIView elements are in the cell's contentview.  I logged the tableviewcell's contentview and I see the two labels and the switch.  From reading other posts, I thought that's all I had to do was put the elements in the UITableViewCell's contentView which they are.  I have some constraints setup as well that IB put in for me to see if that would move the labels when the edit button was selected, but it does not.  It looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to move over those labels when the edit button is selected.  Thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try using tableview reloadInputView or reloadData. If that doesnt work, look at some of tableviews delegate methods, and respond to an event happening to the table or cell using one of those methods